# Is there something awkward in an "the alert followed the meeting"?

Tags: word-usage

I recently came across a question on our sister site, English Language Learners, which was asking about a question the OP had seen in some sort of language test which asked which word should be used to fill in the gap in this sentence (slightly abbreviated for brevity here):

> The heightened alert ____ an emergency meeting with flu experts
> in Geneva

The expected answer was *followed*:

> The heightened alert followed an emergency meeting with flu experts
> in Geneva

Somehow, it doesn't sit right with me that a *heightened alert* can *follow* a meeting. I would be fine with a rephrasing like:

> Following the meeting, the country was placed on high alert.

Or, closer to the original:

> The heightened alert was the result of an emergency meeting with flu experts
> in Geneva

But, for some reason, I am not happy with the idea that *an alert followed* an event. I think I am missing another noun there as I would be OK with *the* announcement *of the heightened alert followed...* It's the alert itself that I feel cannot *follow* a meeting.

Do I have a leg to stand on here? Is there something like the [*licensing* of complements](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/102038/25030) that verbs do perhaps? Or is this just my own personal hangup and there is nothing awkward about the phrase at all?

---

Comment: The context is all: *The outbreak of swine flu that was first detected in Mexico was declared a global epidemic on June 11, 2009. It is the first worldwide epidemic designated by the World Health Organization in 41 years.* It was the flu experts who declared it to be an epidemic: therefore **followed** is correct. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/follow) has "to happen or come after something. *We were not prepared for the events that followed.*"

Comment: @WeatherVane huh? I am well aware of this extremely common meaning and usage of the word _followed_. Please focus on the actual question and example sentence presented here. This isn't about reading comprehension, it is about the specific usage of _followed_ when combined with _heightened alert_ which is what I find jarring. I may well be wrong, of course, but the fact that _followed_ means "to come after something" is not in question.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. It says "I can see how *prompted* would be perfectly natural here" and my comment disagrees. "Prompted" is the wrong sequence of events. The alert was *issued* following a meeting of flu experts. The alert followed it, the *state* of alert followed it.

Comment: Ah. I feel that while _John followed Mary into the building_ is fine, _the alert followed the meeting_ is not and I'm trying to put my finger on why. One possibility is that this is just my own hangup, another is that there is indeed something off with that sentence and I'm wondering what it might be. That's why I linked to the answer explaining how verbs licence different complements, since I think (hope) it might be something along those lines. While _the alert was issued following the meeting_ would be fine, _the heightened alert followed_ feels off. Does that help @WeatherVane?

Comment: @WeatherVane _the alert was issued following..._ is a different case, and I would be perfectly fine with that. It's the specific case of _heightened alert_ and _following_ that I am uncomfortable with. You can _issue_ something _following_ something else, and a _heightened alert_ can be the _result_ or _outcome_ of the meeting, but _The heightened alert followed the meeting_ feels different.

Comment: So you wouldn't like, for example, "A calm followed the storm"? Turning that one round to be "There was a calm following the storm" feels incorrect.

Comment: No, that too seems fine to me. This is precisely why I am asking this question: to try and figure out if there is indeed something that sets the specific example apart. I have no idea why _a calm followed the storm_ doesn't bother me but _the heightened alert followed the meeting_ does. I am pretty sure it is because the alert itself didn't follow, the _issuing_ of the alert did, but I freely admit I'm clutching at straws here.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I removed any mention of _prompted_ since I fear that was distracting from my actual question which is only about the specific use of _followed_ when combined with _heightened alert_ in the absence of any other verb like _issuing_ or noun like _announcement_. I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: If you picture a radio call (red alert) that the committee issued later that day, then that announced labeled warning resulted from the meeting (followed it). Remember that standard tests in language skills ask for the best answer, not the correct one. Even in math, 1/2 will be marked right and 2/4 wrong

Comment: @YosefBaskin yes, I am quite clear about the meaning. And _resulted from_ would be a different issue. _The announcement followed the meeting_ is also fine, but _the red alert followed the meeting_ feels off, like the example in the question.

Comment: My mistake. I thought you were looking for help. No one is putting you down as not clear about the meaning.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I'm sorry, I didn't mean that to come across as aggressive. I am looking for help, but about the specific usage mentioned. This is a really hard thing to articulate, but my issue isn't about meaning; I am a native English speaker and quite familiar with the standard meaning(s) of both _follow_ and _prompt_. The question is about the specific usage. It might help clarify if you read the post I have linked to where Stoney explains about how certain verbs license complements of specific types (or not, I don't know that anything equivalent is happening here).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey lol, but no, this is far from the first time I've encountered _foo followed bar_, that isn't what's tripping me up. It is far more likely that this is just some personal idiosyncrasy of mine, but I'm still holding out (rapidly diminishing) hope that there may be a more general thing going on here.

Comment: Questions asking about personal foibles are off-topic, but it's legitimate (if also off-topic) to criticise the sentence for being vague: was the alert a direct consequence of the meeting; was the meeting one of several factors that led to the alert (e.g. there was a meeting but also other discussions); or were the two connected in time but not in causality?

Comment: @StuartF I am not asking about personal foibles. I believe there is something else here. It is only that I also know I might be wrong and it could be something personal, but that isn't what I am asking about nor what I believe is the case.

Comment: An alert *is* an announcement. A heightened alert is an even bigger announcement.

Comment: @TinfoilHat yeah, I think that's the bit that bugs me. An alert isn't an announcement, it is something that can be announced. _The heightened alert was announced following the meeting_ wouldn't phase me.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey could you please post an answer? The comments seem to have devolved into quoting random pieces of poetry, not related to the question. Perhaps you could collect your views into a coherent answer instead?

Answer (score 1):

- 'Following the meeting, the country was placed on high alert.'

(I'm ignoring the misplaced modifier problem that some will consider serious; see 'Does it really matter if it dangles?' [G Pullum in LanguageLog], the essence of which is given in the [Dangling Participles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148766/dangling-participles/381464#381464) thread.)

[Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/following_3) has the sense (emphasised here, my italics):

> **following** [preposition]:
>
> after or *as a result of* a particular event
>
> - He took charge of the family business following his father's death.

As is obvious in their example, the death of the father was a (main) reason why the subject took control of the business; the father's death was in no way causal, and certainly did not exert persuasion (as say mother, a potential volitional agent, might have done).

The verb 'follow' can certainly be used in a corresponding way:

> **follow** [verb] [transitive]:
>
> 5: to come into existence or take place as a result or consequence of
>
> - *disaster followed the blunder*

Though the definition of the intransitive usage seems more tolerant of the 'hidden human agency' interpretation ('resulted as an agency put into effect a plan to address this situation'):

> **follow** [verb] [intransitive]:
>
> 2: to result or occur as a consequence, effect, or inference [[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/follow)]

And yes, 'follow' can indicate mere sequentiality, but the default readings in the examples above addresses reason/factor informing decision made to address the event/state mentioned.

........

On a separate issue:

- 'The heightened alert followed an emergency meeting with flu experts in Geneva'

sounds more natural than

- 'The alert followed an emergency meeting with flu experts in Geneva'.

Answer (score -1):

> ***alert***
>
> from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 5th
> Edition.
>
> *noun* 
> A condition or period of heightened watchfulness or preparation for action.
>
> https://www.wordnik.com/words/alert

As Tinfoil Hat had implied in a comment underneath the original question, I think the issue for you here may actually be with the word *alert,* which in addition to being an adjective that means "watchful and attentive," can actually also be a noun that means "**a period or state** of watchfulness and attentiveness," which in this case, had been increased after the emergency meeting.

> The heightened *condition of watchfulness* followed an emergency meeting with flu experts in Geneva.

What do you think? Does this help you more readily accept *followed* as a verb  following "the heightened alert"?

Comment: No, I am very familiar with the meanings of _alert_, thank you. I struggle to think what else it could mean in this context.

Comment: TBF, if you were OK with the meaning of the word alert, you'd be OK with it being followed by the word followed . @terdon

Comment: My issue is more with the lack of a verb. In this context, an alert needs to be announced or issued, or altered, or something. An alert was issued following the meeting would be fine, for example.

Comment: In that case, how do you feel about Edwin Ashworth's answer up above? I had posted an alternative answer using the same definition for followed as he had (now deleted). Just wondering your take on his suggestion. (Feel free to continue the conversation under his answer, not here.) @terdon